# column count doesnt match value count at row 1 for data entry

Tags: java, sql

SQL exception column count doesn't match value count at row 1

In NetBeans version 8.2 while using a form in swing `apk`. I am getting this error

```
int i=s.executeUpdate("insert into register(FULL_NAME,EMAIL,PASSWORD,CPASSWORD,MOBILE_NO,GENDER,DEPARTMENT,HOBBIES,ADDRESS) values ('"+fname1+","+email1+","+pass1+","+cpass1+","+num1+","+gender+","+dept1+","+hobby+","+address1+"')");
```

i want values to be sent to SQL database or MySql workbench

Comment: an easy way to find the issue would be, save your sql statement string in a variable, output that variable in the console or a debug file, run that SQL directly in your MySQL Workbench, you will figure out the issue :) I am guessing it could be due to missing single quotes encompassing the field values. I might be wrong though, but saving the exact sql statement from your code and running it in the workbench will give you some insight

Comment: Please see about SQL Injection and use `PreparedStatement` instead. It is safer and more readable !

Answer (score 0):

Your table has 9 columns but you only insert values to 1 columns.

You should search to use `parameterized query` or use this workaround (parameter varchar type is enquoted by `''`, number type isn't)

```
int i = s.executeUpdate(
        "INSERT INTO register(
            full_name,
            email,
            password,
            cpassword,
            mobile_no,
            gender,
            department,
            hobbies,
            address) 
        VALUES ('" 
        + fname1
        + "', '" + email1
        + "', '" + pass1
        + "', '" + cpass1
        + "'," + num1
        + ", '" + gender
        + "', '" + dept1
        + "', '" + hobby
        + "', '" + address1 
        + "')"
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
int i=s.executeUpdate("insert into register(FULL_NAME,EMAIL,PASSWORD,CPASSWORD,MOBILE_NO,GENDER,DEPARTMENT,HOBBIES,ADDRESS) "
                + "values ('"+fname1+"','"+email1+"','"+pass1+"','"+cpass1+"','"+num1+"','"+gender+"','"+dept1+"','"+hobby+"','"+address1+"')");
```

as per your current scenario you are passing single value instead of 9 due ' single qote

Answer (score 0):

Your query, after all concatenations of the strings should look like this: 
`int i=s.executeUpdate("insert into 
register(FULL_NAME,EMAIL,PASSWORD,CPASSWORD,MOBILE_NO,GENDER,DEPARTMENT,HOBBIES,ADDRESS) values ('personName','personalEmail',..))`

You should surround each String with single quote when you make a query in SQL

In your example after concatenation it will look like this:
`int i=s.executeUpdate("insert into 
register(FULL_NAME,EMAIL,PASSWORD,CPASSWORD,MOBILE_NO,GENDER,DEPARTMENT,HOBBIES,ADDRESS) values ('personName,personalEmail,..'))`

and will be interpreted like you gave value only for the first column FULL_NAME